# Powershell SQL Server database restore (with CDC)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-restore

I am trying to create a Powershell script to restore database to my laptop from my desktop. I have a script which creates the backup files and have almost got the restore script working apart from a strange error I get with a CDC enabled database. What I end up with is an off-line single user database. I have to bring it back on-line and change it back to multi-user manually. Here are the relevant bits of my powershell code ...

```ps
$instance = "(local)"
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $instance

$restore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore
$restore.Action = "Database"
$restore.Database = $dbname
$restore.NoRecovery = $false
$restore.ReplaceDatabase = $true
$restore.Devices.AddDevice($filename, "File")
$restore.SqlRestore($server)
```

I get an error message saying ...

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not update the metadata that indicates database xxxxx is not enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command '[sys].[sp_MScdc_ddl_database triggers 'drop''. The error returned was 15517: 'Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission'*

and a bit further down ...

> *The database has been left offline. See the topic MSSQL_ENG003165 in SQL Server Books Online.*

further down ...

> *Converting database 'xxxxx' from version 655 to the current version 661.
> Database 'xxxxx' running the upgrade step from version 655 to version 660.
> Database 'xxxxx' running the upgrade step from version 660 to 661.*

While I can get the database back to a useable state, I would ideally like to have it completely scripted. The idea of this is that I can run the backup script on my desktop and then run the restore script on my laptop, which then restores the databases on my laptop so I have a working copy of the same database for when I need to work remotely.

Any insights would be great, even better if someone has come across and solved the same problem.

Comment: I think this is a bug that was fixed in a recent CU.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with CU. what does it stand for and how can I get the bug fix? I'm assuming the U stands for Update.

Comment: Search for cumulative update. I can't seem to find the relevant one right now. If you can, just install the newest one.

Comment: I see a KeepReplication property on the restore class you could try setting it to false http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx

Comment: I applied the CU#14 and I still have the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I had to set an explicit CDC setting in a restore script, I did something like:

```
    $script_lines = $restore.script( $server )
    $script_lines += ', keep_cdc'
    $script = ''
    foreach ($line in $script_lines) {
            $script += $line
    }

    $script
    invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server.name -Query $script -QueryTimeout 65535
```

Comment: It worked after a few minor modifications. I had to execute the script using the master database. I got that like so ... $masterDatabase = $server.Databases | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "master" } ... I then executed the script like so ... $masterDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery($script)